# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode loosing HTML tags in email

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, email

I'm trying to send emails which contains html tags using the following code.

```
string host = "smtp.office365.com", subject = "", fromAddr = "fromAddress";
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(host, 587);
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress(fromAddr);
            msg.Subject = subject;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            string emailBody = "Hello <strong>World</strong>";
            msg.Body = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(emailBody);
            string toAddrList = "toaddress";
            foreach (string addr in toAddrList.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                msg.To.Add(addr.Trim());
            }

            System.Net.NetworkCredential credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email", "pass", "");
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = credential;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Send(msg);
```

The emails are being sent but html tags are not being render, emails are received with simple text like

[image]

But if I remove System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode method and pass the emailBody as it is, then it renders html tags properly in email.

Can someone please tell me how can I make it work so that I dont have to remove the System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode method and keeping html tags as well.

Thanks

Comment: You'll find it easier to get help if you tell people what programming language you are using.

Comment: The utility does exactly what you ask it to do: `For example, when embedded in a block of text, the characters < and > are encoded as &lt; and &gt; for HTTP transmission` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmlencode?view=net-5.0